# Storing feasible solutions in terms of original variables

Tags: scip

I want to store a feasible solution from an event handler that catches the `SCIP_EVENTTYPE_BESTSOLFOUND` event, and later I would like to give this solution as an heuristic solution to another SCIP instance that is optimizing the same problem but with different parameter settings (this could be in a subsequent optimization or in parallel).
My problem is that the solution I get from using `SCIPgetBestSol()` will be in terms of the transformed problem, which can be different from the transformed problem in the second SCIP instance.

Would turning presolve off (using `SCIPsetPresolving()`) be enough for ensuring that SCIP is always referring to the original variables within callback functions? 
Is there a particular way that you would recomend for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your event handler can access the array of original variables (`SCIPget(N)OrigVars()` does the trick). You can always query solution values of original variables, *even from transformed solutions*, using `SCIPgetSolVal()`, and store the values in a solution created via `SCIPcreateOrigSol()`.

In order to feed this solution into a different SCIP instance, you have to get the mapping between variables of the primary and secondary SCIP instance right. Create a new solution for the secondary SCIP instance, and set the solution value of a variable to the value of its (pre-)image variable in the primary SCIP.

Comment: Thanks Gregor! Two followup questions: Does this mean that I don't need to turn off presolve? Would this also hold for branching rules (being able to always refer to original variables)?

Comment: The mapping challenge arises because SCIP **always** transforms (ie copies) the original problem to have a working copy. Even disabling presolving does not prevent problem transformation. Branching on original variable information is also possible, but a bit more tricky than accessing solution values because of the different statuses a variable can have.